# Ошибки при запуске простейшего теста в яндекс.танк

Tags: яндекс-танк

Только начал знакомство с Я.Танк.
Написал по примеру простейший конфиг,при запуске ругается на кодировку.
Запускаю на ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64
Содержимое файла load.ini:

```
    [Phantom]
address=62.109.6.185
port = 80
rps_schedule = const (1.50s) line(1,100,10m) step(40.1.5.8s)
headers = [Host: 62.109.6.185]
uris=  /
  /login/
  /offerslist/
```

Вывод в консоли:

```
$ yandex-tank

11:35:51 [WARNING] /etc/yandex-tank is not accessible to get configs list
11:35:51 [INFO] No config passed via cmdline, using ./load.ini
11:35:51 [INFO] Loading configs...
11:35:51 [INFO] Loading plugins...
11:35:51 [INFO] Performing test
11:35:51 [INFO] Configuring plugins...
11:35:51 [INFO] Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 261, in perform_test
    self.core.plugins_configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 222, in plugins_configure
    plugin.configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/plugin.py", line 92, in configure
    self.phantom.read_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/utils.py", line 78, in read_config
    self.phout_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 387, in set_option
    self.config.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 582, in flush
    self.config.write(handle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 939, in write
    self._sections[section].items(), d)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 951, in _write_section
    fp.write("{0}{1}\n".format(key, value))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-36: ordinal not in range(128)

11:35:51 [ERROR] 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-36: ordinal not in range(128)
11:35:51 [INFO] Trying to shutdown gracefully...
11:35:51 [INFO] Finishing test...
11:35:51 [ERROR] Failed finishing plugin <yandextank.plugins.Aggregator.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7f294afde210>: 'Plugin' object has no attribute 'drain'
11:35:51 [INFO] Finishing monitoring
11:35:51 [INFO] Post-processing test...
11:35:51 [INFO] Artifacts dir: /home/starcode/Документы/AutoTests/loading/test/logs/2016-12-06_11-35-51.hgLEMw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file tankcore.py, line 412
11:35:51 [INFO] Done graceful shutdown
11:35:51 [INFO] Close allocated resources...
11:35:51 [INFO] Done performing test with code 1
```

Comment: Вместо `<pre>` удобно использовать отступ в четыре пробела, это разметка Markdown. Хоткей Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1):

С кодировкой решил проблему, добавив -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

в /usr/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py

Но остались эти ошибки:

```
$ yandex-tank
12:07:12 [WARNING] /etc/yandex-tank is not accessible to get configs list
12:07:12 [INFO] No config passed via cmdline, using ./load.ini
12:07:12 [INFO] Loading configs...
12:07:12 [INFO] Loading plugins...
12:07:12 [INFO] Performing test
12:07:12 [INFO] Configuring plugins...
12:07:12 [INFO] Resolved 127.0.0.1 into 127.0.0.1:80
12:07:12 [INFO] Configuring StepperWrapper...
12:07:12 [INFO] Preparing test...
12:07:12 [INFO] Checking tank resources...
12:07:12 [INFO] Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 262, in perform_test
    self.core.plugins_prepare_test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 233, in plugins_prepare_test
    plugin.prepare_test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/plugin.py", line 100, in prepare_test
    self.config = self.phantom.compose_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/utils.py", line 106, in compose_config
    streams_config += stream.compose_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/utils.py", line 278, in compose_config
    self.stepper_wrapper.prepare_stepper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 197, in prepare_stepper
    self.stpd = self.__get_stpd_filename()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 252, in __get_stpd_filename
    raise RuntimeError("Neither ammofile nor uris specified")
RuntimeError: Neither ammofile nor uris specified

12:07:12 [ERROR] Neither ammofile nor uris specified
12:07:12 [INFO] Trying to shutdown gracefully...
12:07:12 [INFO] Finishing test...
12:07:12 [ERROR] Failed finishing plugin : 'Plugin' object has no attribute 'drain'
12:07:12 [INFO] Finishing monitoring
12:07:12 [INFO] Post-processing test...
12:07:12 [INFO] Artifacts dir: /home/starcode/Документы/AutoTests/loading/test/logs/2016-12-06_12-07-12.OmIl0k
12:07:12 [INFO] Done graceful shutdown
12:07:12 [INFO] Close allocated resources...
12:07:12 [INFO] Done performing test with code 1
```

Comment: "Neither ammofile nor uris specified" - танку нужно указать отдельно файл с "патронами" либо указать список запросов в конфиге load.conf

Comment: на кириллицу в путях мы не рассчитывали, да)

Comment: @r2d2 может быть, опубликуете ответ с примером конфига?

Comment: до меня вдруг дошло в чем дело. @Андрей, напишите [phantom] с маленькой буквы. //похоже в st нельзя призвать пользователя с кириллическим ником?

Comment: @NickVolynkin мы делали туториал, с примерами, например с указанием запросов в конфиге https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#uri-style-uris-in-load-ini. Эти примеры рабочие. В следующий раз постараюсь сразу дать ссылку на readthedocs

Comment: @r2d2 где нельзя призвать? На stackoverflow можно, но в одном сообщении не более одного пользователя.

Comment: у меня в safari дополнение имени, если набрать @ и далее ник кириллицей, не работает, поэтому подумал что и призвать не получится

Comment: @r2d2 некрокомментарий: автора вопроса/ответа, под которым пишется комментарий, нельзя указать - если в комментарии не указан чей-то еще ник, уведомление и так уйдет к нему.